# SQL Server: Flag only First duplicate row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to flag only the first duplicate `ID`-`VL` combination in the dataset shown below. Column `FirstOccurence` is what I want the end result to be.

```
ID  VL  FirstOccurence
1   a   1
1   b   1
2   a   1
2   a   0
3   a   1
3   a   0
4   a   1
4   a   0
5   a   1
5   b   1
5   a   0
```

There is currently not a unique index available in the original table.
Is there any way to do this with for instance the `LAG`-functionality? I cannot find any examples online that result in the flagging of duplicates. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Kind regards,
Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is with `ROW_NUMBER()` along with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
     ID
    ,VL
    ,CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, VL ORDER BY ID, VL) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FirstOccurance
FROM dbo.example
ORDER BY
     ID
    ,VL
    ,FirstOccurance;
```

Results:

```
+----+----+----------------+
| ID | VL | FirstOccurance |
+----+----+----------------+
|  1 | a  |              1 |
|  1 | b  |              1 |
|  2 | a  |              0 |
|  2 | a  |              1 |
|  3 | a  |              0 |
|  3 | a  |              1 |
|  4 | a  |              0 |
|  4 | a  |              1 |
|  5 | a  |              0 |
|  5 | a  |              1 |
|  5 | b  |              1 |
+----+----+----------------+
```

Note that this result order differs from your end result. If there are one or more columns present in the table that provide the same ordering as the results in you question, specify that in the `ORDER BY` clause instead.